# Hamburger menu expands and closes right away

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ipad, menu, responsive

I have hamburger menu on my wordpress website. When it comes to responsiveness, all is working but IPad portrait. The problem is - when I click the hamburger menu, it expands for a second and then closes right away. It should stay open, instead. I have the following app.js file:

```
!function ($) {


 /* COLLAPSE PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
  * ================================ */

  var Collapse = function (element, options) {
    this.$element = $(element)
    this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.collapse.defaults, options)

    if (this.options.parent) {
      this.$parent = $(this.options.parent)
    }

    this.options.toggle && this.toggle()
  }

  Collapse.prototype = {

    constructor: Collapse

  , dimension: function () {
      var hasWidth = this.$element.hasClass('width')
      return hasWidth ? 'width' : 'height'
    }

  , show: function () {
      var dimension
        , scroll
        , actives
        , hasData

      if (this.transitioning || this.$element.hasClass('in')) return

      dimension = this.dimension()
      scroll = $.camelCase(['scroll', dimension].join('-'))
      actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('> .accordion-group > .in')

      if (actives && actives.length) {
        hasData = actives.data('collapse')
        if (hasData && hasData.transitioning) return
        actives.collapse('hide')
        hasData || actives.data('collapse', null)
      }

      this.$element[dimension](0)
      this.transition('addClass', $.Event('show'), 'shown')
      $.support.transition && this.$element[dimension](this.$element[0][scroll])
    }

  , hide: function () {
      var dimension
      if (this.transitioning || !this.$element.hasClass('in')) return
      dimension = this.dimension()
      this.reset(this.$element[dimension]())
      this.transition('removeClass', $.Event('hide'), 'hidden')
      this.$element[dimension](0)
    }

  , reset: function (size) {
      var dimension = this.dimension()

      this.$element
        .removeClass('collapse')
        [dimension](size || 'auto')
        [0].offsetWidth

      this.$element[size !== null ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapse')

      return this
    }

  , transition: function (method, startEvent, completeEvent) {
      var that = this
        , complete = function () {
            if (startEvent.type == 'show') that.reset()
            that.transitioning = 0
            that.$element.trigger(completeEvent)
          }

      this.$element.trigger(startEvent)

      if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

      this.transitioning = 1

      this.$element[method]('in')

      $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('collapse') ?
        this.$element.one($.support.transition.end, complete) :
        complete()
    }

  , toggle: function () {
      this[this.$element.hasClass('in') ? 'hide' : 'show']()
    }

  }


 /* COLLAPSE PLUGIN DEFINITION
  * ========================== */

  var old = $.fn.collapse

  $.fn.collapse = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('collapse')
        , options = $.extend({}, $.fn.collapse.defaults, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
      if (!data) $this.data('collapse', (data = new Collapse(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }

  $.fn.collapse.defaults = {
    toggle: true
  }

  $.fn.collapse.Constructor = Collapse


 /* COLLAPSE NO CONFLICT
  * ==================== */

  $.fn.collapse.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.collapse = old
    return this
  }


 /* COLLAPSE DATA-API
  * ================= */

  $(document).on('click.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this), href
      , target = $this.attr('data-target')
        || e.preventDefault()
        || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') //strip for ie7
      , option = $(target).data('collapse') ? 'toggle' : $this.data()
    $this[$(target).hasClass('in') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapsed')
    $(target).collapse(option)
  })

}(window.jQuery);


jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var lastId,
        topMenu = $("#top-navigation"),
        topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight(),
        // All list items
        menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
        // Anchors corresponding to menu items
        scrollItems = menuItems.map(function () {
            var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
            if (item.length) {
                return item;
            }
        });


    // Bind to scroll
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        //Display or hide scroll to top button 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 330) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top animated fadeInDown');
        } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top animated fadeInDown');
        }

        // Get container scroll position
        var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight + 10;

        // Get id of current scroll item
        var cur = scrollItems.map(function () {
            if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
                return this;
        });

        // Get the id of the current element
        cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
        var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

        if (lastId !== id) {
            lastId = id;
            // Set/remove active class
            menuItems
                .parent().removeClass("active")
                .end().filter("[href=#" + id + "]").parent().addClass("active");
        }
    });

    /*
    Function for scroliing to top
    ************************************/
    $('.scrollup').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
        return false;
    });


    $(window).load(function () {
        function filterPath(string) {
            return string.replace(/^\//, '').replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/, '').replace(/\/$/, '');
        }
        $('a[href*=#]').each(function () {
            if (filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname) && location.hostname == this.hostname && this.hash.replace(/#/, '')) {
                var $targetId = $(this.hash),
                    $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;

                if ($target) {

                    $(this).click(function () {

                        //Hack collapse top navigation after clicking
                        topMenu.parent().attr('style', 'height:0px').removeClass('in'); //Close navigation
                        $('.navbar .btn-navbar').addClass('collapsed');
                        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 63;
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: targetOffset
                        }, 800);
                        return false;
                    });



                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I also have the folllowing css file:

```
.animated{-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;-ms-animation-fill-mode:both;-o-animation-fill-mode:both;animation-fill-mode:both;-webkit-animation-duration:1s;-moz-animation-duration:1s;-ms-animation-duration:1s;-o-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;}
.animated.hinge{-webkit-animation-duration:1s;-moz-animation-duration:1s;-ms-animation-duration:1s;-o-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;}


@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateY(-20px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.fadeInDown {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

I am desperate to make this work, but I have no idea how, since my experience with this is not very much. Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanx

Comment: Do you have a working version you can share? It may have to do with the click handler but there is too much code to determine it just by reading (at least for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours of desperation, I realized that I had one .`js` file which was conflicting with other .js files. Since that particular `.js` file was connected to hamburger menu only, all I did was rename it, therefore made it non-existant for the entire page and voila, everything worked perfectly. I hope this helps someone. Always check whether your `.js` files are conflicting each other.